# How to trasform a microsoft sql server report service in web application

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How can i trasform a microsoft sql server report service in web application or something that i can access on the net?

thanks to all that would help me

Comment: So you're looking to embed a Reporting Services report in a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a bunch of different options - see:

[Integrating Reporting Services into Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697(SQL.90).aspx)
[Using the Report Server Web Service/SOAP APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787(SQL.90).aspx)
[Extending/Integrating Reporting Services using RS Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155076(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's a `asp:ReportViewer` control, which allows you to either display a local *.rdlc file containing a report definition, or you can also hook that up to a server-side *.rdl file on your reporting server.

Is that what you're looking for? It can render and show the report you defined on a ASP.NET page.